# How to Filter Symfony Form Entity Output depending on unrelated relationship

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, formbuilder

**I have three entities like so:**
-Available-Teams   (Managed by Admins)
-Player-PreConfig (Managed by Admins)
-Player-Self]     (Managed by User(Player itself))
[image]
Available-Teams: 
--> All available teams

Player-PreConfig: 
--> Here the Administrators are able to preselect teams in which a player is allowed to play.   (First-Filter - Many2Many: Available-Teams<->Player-PreConfig) - Lots of checkboxes in the view.

Player-Self:
--> Here the Player should be able to select the teams (multiple) he would like to play in. But he should not get listed ALL possible Available-Teams, but only the remaining ones.

**Classes**

```
/**
 * TeamsPlayerBundle\Entity\Teams
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="team")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Team
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
           
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PreConfig", mappedBy="teams", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     **/
    private $configs;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Player", mappedBy="teams2show", cascade={"persist"})
     **/
    private $players;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configs = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->players = new ArrayCollection();
    }
 
 (... setters and getters) 

###################################################

/**
 * TeamsPlayerBundle\Entity\PreConfig
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="preconfig")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PreConfig
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
   
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Teams", inversedBy="configs", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="preconfig_teams)
     **/
    private $teams;    

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->teams = new ArrayCollection();
    }    
    
 (... setters and getters)

 ####################################################
 
 /**
 * TeamsPlayerBundle\Entity\Player
 *
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="player")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Player
{   
    /**
     * @var integer $player_id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $player_id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $name
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Team", inversedBy="player", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="player_team",
     *                      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="player_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *                      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *     )
     **/
    private $teams2show;    
    
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->teams2show = new ArrayCollection();
    }     

  (... setters and getters)
```

**Right now I have this FormType: I try to solve with Query_Builder as suggested by "Viktor77"**

```
namespace TeamsPlayerBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use TeamsPlayerBundle\Entity\Player;

class Teams2ShowType extends AbstractType
{ 
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
                
  $builder
        ->add('teams2show', 'entity', array(
                   'class' => 'TeamsPlayerBundle\Entity\PreConfig',
                        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($cid) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                            ->add('orderBy', 'c.name ASC')
                                            ->innerJoin('c.teams', 'c2')
                                            ->where('c2.id = :configId')
                                            ->setParameter('configId', $cid);
                                            
                        },
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'property_path' => 'teams2show',
                    'property' => 'name'
                    ))           
    ;
...<br />
```

**For Your Reference: => My first Form looked like this:**

```
class Teams2ShowType extends AbstractType
{ 
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('teams2show', 'entity', array(
                       'multiple' => true,
                       'expanded' => true,
```

**The problem was as follows:**
If I render the form right now everything works fine, but a huge list of checkboxes gets rendered. The whole entity is presented.

Sure because I have no idea, how to only populate the remaining entities depending on the many-to-many relationship Available-Teams<->Player-PreConfig).

Because obviously, my actual Teams2ShowType has no idea, that only the remaining teams should show up.

I have already tried a lot and read a lot (query_builder, model transformer, etc..), but I could not get it right.

My real example (in the company) has to do something with licensors and partner configuration, but I wanted to present this question in a more comprehensible scenario.

I do not know of any best practices on how to implement this right.

*Thank you so much for your help in advance I have already tried to solve that issue more than 3-4days.* 
Kind regards,

Comment: I have added image of classes via Link as i have not enough reputation yet to embed image. regards.

Comment: I have added the most important steps of the classes for your reference. (please keep in mind, that I am a Symfony noob, and things can be wrong or not best practice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

query_builder option is the way to go. Just use Doctrine Query Builder API to get only the entities you need to be rendered in your form and not all of them

Comment: Thank you so much, i was thinking about query builder! But i was not sure if this is the best practice. Well, now i know this is the right direction to investigate. If someone would write an example on how to render an entity, but only values from many2many from another relationship (which has no relationship to that entity directly), that would be so much of a help. Thx - I will try hard to figure it out ... but any help is much appreciated.